# My Android phone not showing up in Dalvik Debug Monitor

Tags: android

I have USB Debugging checked. I can deploy my Android application to my phone. And test. But why my phone is not showing up in Dalvik Debug Monitor.

Where as it works fine with Eclipse for development and deployment?

Once I have taken the screenshot from here. But now its not showing up.

What's went wrong?

**Edit** See the screenshot. Device is in offline mode. I have seen stacktrace of exception on command line, as following:

```
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device offline
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:736)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)

    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:276)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.SysinfoPanel.loadFromDevice(SysinfoPanel.java:15
```

[image]

Comment: can you open a command shell and issue the command 'adb devices'? It could be that adb server on the host isn't running. Disconnect your phone, then try 'adb -kill-server' followed by 'adb devices' to reload the host server.  Might need to reset the phone.  I find the phone daemon occasionally stops responding and a swift kick is all it takes.

Comment: Hi Eric. Thank you very much. I did the same. I run the abd command. Killed the server. Run the adb command again to start the deamon. And when I opened DDMS, I can see my device and I can capture the screenshot. +1. Post it in answers, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a command shell and issue the command 'adb devices'. It could be that adb server on the host isn't running.

Disconnect your phone, then try 'adb kill-server' followed by 'adb devices' to reload the host server. You may need to reset the phone. I find the phone daemon occasionally stops responding and a swift kick is all it takes.