# Dalvik Debug Monitor not showing my phone

Tags: android

I have downloaded and installed the SDK. But my phone is not getting shown in the Dalvik Debug monitor.

Please help me, what is going wrong? I have killed the server. And restarted. But adb devices is not listing my device. I know while development in eclipse, I cant get my application running on my phone rather on emulator.

[image]

I executed these commands too:

```
E:\programs\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb kill-server

E:\programs\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached


E:\programs\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools>
```

PS: I re-installed my SDK. Previously I was having a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462851/my-android-phone-not-showing-up-in-dalvik-debug-monitor) when my phone was offline. But that was resolved. I followed the same steps. But no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do have Google USB Driver package revision 4 installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install USB driver of your device.

Comment: When I connect my phone, I didnt get the notification from Windows 7 about installing the device driver.

Comment: I think you can still try to setup driver or check your cable.

Comment: You have to go to the device manufacturer and get the usb driver
http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html

Comment: Yes Sahin, I guess I should try to run Delvik after installing Samsung Kies. I am using Samsung Galaxy Ace.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the device manager's page inside Windows. If the phone is flagged with a warning sign, the device wasn't installed correctly and you need to find the appropriate drivers for your phone. The drivers from Google doesn't always work correctly. 
I've had loads of trouble with the drivers for HTC devices on Windows 7 x64 but after I've changed to linux I never have any problems with the drivers :P

Comment: Well it's redicoulously bad, that just for driver I installed a mammoth Samsung Kies. That I dont want to use even. Google should take care of these tiny drivers.

Comment: What happens if you just uninstall Kies? Does it take down the drivers for the phone as well? For HTC I found the drivers without HTC Sync, but it took a while to find the right ones.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the usb driver.
What kind of phone do you have?
For HTC devices the easiest way is to install htc sync. It will install the right drivers.
[Link to HTC Sync](http://www.htc.com/de/SupportViewNews.aspx?dl_id=1073&news_id=910). 
For the emulator you have to create a virtual device first.

Comment: I guess I need to install Samsung Kies. Let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Phone > Settings > Applications > Development > USB debugging - this needs to be selected.